# Where is Virtuemart assests connect to page?

Tags: javascript, joomla, virtuemart

I can't find where are js assets connected to main page. These one, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/jquery.noConflict.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmsite.js">
```

The main problem is, that I have 2 sites, with exactly the same configurations in Virtuemart and most Joomla settings too. But here:
http://www.fenix-gold.com/katalog/rasprodazha/komplekt-s-topazom-0237-0337-fenix-gold.html
neither 1 script is connected, but the same time here: 
http://www.st.fenix-gold.com/katalog/rasprodazha/koltso-s-topazamii-fenix-gold.html
all scripts are connected.
Does anybody coud help me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that it depends on the view tmplate, because in category list it works. So, I changed my views/productdetails/default.php file and now it works!